# knockout observable array is not updating view on removing elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Here is my view model code

```
var TopicsViewModel = function() {
var self = this;

var fakeTopicData =
 [

 ];


self.createProfile = function () {
    alert("came to create profile");
};

self.editProfile = function () {
    alert("came to edit profile");
};

self.removeProfile = function (profile) {
    alert("came to remove profile");
    fakeTopicData.pop();
    self.topicsArr(fakeTopicData);
};



var refresh = function() {
    self.topicsArr = fakeTopicData;

};


self.topicsArr = ko.observableArray([]);
refresh();

  };


  ko.applyBindings(new TopicsViewModel());
```

Here is my html for the view:

```
<hr /> 
<hr /> 

<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr >
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Why</th>

    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach : topicsArr">   
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text :area"> </td>
            <td class=""><a data-bind="text:name, click:$parent.editProfile"></a></td>           
            <td data-bind="text:link"> </td>
            <td data-bind="text:desc">  </td>
            <td data-bind="text:why" ></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-bind="click:$parent.removeProfile">remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

 <script src="~/Scripts/Topic.js"></script>
```

The view initially display all the Topics in my fakeData Array.
On clicking the remove Button, I am trying to remove an element from the array, and expected the view to refresh and not show the removed item any more. However the view still shows all the 3 topics.

Could someone please point to what I might be doing wrong.
I spend a long time researching the other similar queries on stackoverflow, but am still stuck. Thanks so much for any insight into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing your observable array called topicsarr with one which isn't observable in your refresh method...

Change

```
var refresh = function() {
    self.topicsArr = fakeTopicData;

};
```

to

```
var refresh = function() {
    self.topicsArr(fakeTopicData);

};
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I kept staring at my code and did not catch that. That fixed my problem, and my view now refreshes with the array changes.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 issues in your code.
**First**, you are setting your observableArray `topicsArr` with *non* observableArray or normal array in `refresh` function. Instead use `self.topicsArr(fakeTopicData)`

**Second**, in function `removeProfile` you are using `pop()` to remove `profile` element. From KnockoutJS documentation:

> myObservableArray.pop() removes the last value from the array and
>   returns it

So, it's better to use `remove(item)` and pass to it your `profile` element or loop through your array and remove that specific item

> myObservableArray.remove(someItem) removes all values that equal
>   someItem and returns them as an array

Comment: Thanks so much. What you mentioned was indeed the issue, and it works now, after making the changes you suggested.

Comment: @RekhaJayaram you welcome. if my code works fine, would you please mark it as answer